# Problem with native image in Quarkus and MongoPanache

Tags: quarkus

I have a problem when builing native quarkus image  and try to use mongo panache query.
If i using dev profile or builing normal jar everything working.

Here is my Dockerfile.native

```
## Stage 1 : build with maven builder image with native capabilities
FROM quay.io/quarkus/centos-quarkus-maven:19.2.1 AS build
COPY backend /usr/src/app/backend
COPY frontend /usr/src/app/frontend
COPY pom.xml /usr/src/app/
USER root
RUN chown -R quarkus /usr/src/app
USER quarkus
RUN cd /usr/src/app/ && mvn clean package -Pnative -Dnative-image.xmx=4g
RUN mkdir -p /tmp/ssl-libs/lib \
  && cp /opt/graalvm/jre/lib/security/cacerts /tmp/ssl-libs \
  && cp /opt/graalvm/jre/lib/amd64/libsunec.so /tmp/ssl-libs/lib/

## Stage 2 : create the docker final image
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal
WORKDIR /work/
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/backend/target/*-runner /work/application
COPY --from=build /tmp/ssl-libs/ /work/
RUN chmod 775 /work
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["./application", "-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0", "-Djava.library.path=/work/lib", "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/work/cacerts"]
```

```
 ERROR [io.qua.ver.htt.run.QuarkusErrorHandler] (vert.x-worker-thread-1) HTTP Request to /api/budget failed, error id: 86ff4366-b0d2-49c5-87f7-e6eee9d71feb-1: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class domain.Budget.
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:106)
```

Did anyone have a similar problem?

EDIT

domain (Period and Category has also default construstors)

```
@MongoEntity(collection = "Budget")
public class Budget {

    private ObjectId id;
    private Period period;
    private List<Category> categories;

    public Budget() {
        period = new Period();

        categories = new ArrayList<>();
    }

//business method getter setters...

}
```

repository

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class BudgetRepository implements PanacheMongoRepository<Budget> {

}
```

controller

```
    @GET
    @Path("/budget")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response budget() {
        Budget budget = repository.listAll().get(0);

        return Response.ok(budget).build();
    }
```

Comment: Can you share some code: at least your `domain.Budget` class and the resource endpoint ?

Comment: Yes, i add this in edit section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GraalVM native-image needs to know wich classes needs to be accessible by relfection. As your REST endpoint use a `Response` return type, Quarkus cannot enlist for reflection your `Budget` class automaticaly so you need to use the `@RegisterFroReflection` annotation for this.

There is a PR that will do it for you, so you will soon no more need to do it by yourself: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/6326/files

But as long as this is not merged, you need to add the `@RegisterFroReflection` annotation on your `Budget` class.

Comment: The PR has been merged so staring with the upcomming Quarkus 1.2 this shoud be fixed.